# Invalid Version Format Issue with CMake in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, cmake, versioning, build-automation, cmakelists-options

I am encountering an inconsistency when executing `CMake` through Jenkins compared to my local environment.

Locally, I utilise `build.sh` to run `CMake` without any issues. However, in Jenkins, I get the following error:

```objectivec
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:49 (project):
    
VERSION "-128-NOTFOUND.-128-NOTFOUND.-128-NOTFOUND" format invalid.
```

The related section in CMakeLists.txt (line 49) is:

```
project(myproject VERSION ${VERSION_MAJOR}.${VERSION_MINOR}.${VERSION_PATCH}
  DESCRIPTION "myproject"
  LANGUAGES C CXX)
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)
```

I tried clearing cache on Jenkinsfile like this, but never worked:

```kotlin
stage("Cmake") {
  steps {
    script {
      // Clear CMake Cache 
      def clearcache = "${WORKSPACE}/build"
      sh "rm -rf ${clearcache}" // Modified to remove directory recursively
      cmakeRun()
    }
  }
}
```

Why might this version format error be occurring only in Jenkins, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: The variables `VERSION_MAJOR`, `VERSION_MINOR` and `VERSION_PATCH` are set by your **specific project**. We don't know how exactly your project calculates values for these variables. And we don't know why your project sets the variables to `-128-NOTFOUND`, which is definitely incorrect value for a version's component. Normally, `-NOTFOUND` suffix means that `find_path` or other `find_*` command has failed to find requested file. Try to debug your project using that hint.